# Silverstripe 3.2: Get ID from certain Folder

Tags: directory, silverstripe

I want to get the ID of a certain folder to pass it to another function.

Here is my code:

```
public function getFolderParentID() {
    $folderID = File::get()
            ->filter(array(
                'Filename' => 'assets/myfolder/folder/',
             ))
             ->limit(1);

    return $folderID->ID;
}
```

This does not return anything.

I have also tried `$folderID = Folder::get()` but this does not work either.

How do I get the ID of a folder by it's path name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `first()` instead of `limit(1)` like so:

```
public function getFolderParentID() {
    $folder = File::get()
            ->filter(array(
                'Filename' => 'assets/myfolder/folder/',
             ))->first();

    if ($folder) {
        return $folder->ID;
    }

    return false;
}
```

The reason the original code was not returning anything is because `File::get()->limit(1)` will return a `DataList` of `File` objects, not a single `File` object. We need to get the `File` object out of the list to then ask for it's `ID`. `File::get()->first()` will return the `File` object.